# Call to UrlMkGetSessionOption for URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT always returns E_OUTOFMEMORY

Tags: windows, urlmon

[image: call to UrlMkGetSessionOption]

However, it correctly fills up return string buffer(char*) for UserAgent String.
URLMon.dll version : 11.0.20161.1000  - 64 bit.
Platform Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Indeed, I'm encountering the same issue, although the buffer is filled up correctly. Sounds like the return value should be ignored...

Answer (score 1):

I am using ObtainUserAgentString, which return a char* buffer, and it seems to work for me as of now.